# How do I install ROS Noetic on AWS Workspaces

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently started working in AWS Workspaces on Windows 11, decision came from above my pay grade.  Previous development has been done on Ubuntu.

So I try to install ros using "sudo apt install" from a terminal window and I get the error that apt command not found.  So I try the AWS software installer, yum as I understand.  I search in yum for ros but I am unable to find it.

I am **not** using the robot or anything like that, we're using ros for another application that we had already developed on Ubuntu.

Has anyone been able to install ros in AWS Workspaces?

Thanks,
Doug

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410548/how-do-i-install-ros-noetic-on-aws-workspaces/) by [raider83](https://answers.ros.org/users/115758/raider83/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Amazon Workspaces supports Amazon Linux, Ubuntu and Windows 10 as operating systems. From your question I understand that  you are running Amazon Linux. ROS Noetic officially supports installation on Ubuntu and Debian, and experimental installations on Windows and Arch Linux ([source](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation)).  Amazon Linux is not supported by ROS, but it is possible to build it from source following the instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Source).

Another way to go about it is to use Docker. You can install Docker on AWS Linux, and then use the [ROS Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/).

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2022-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raider83](https://answers.ros.org/users/115758/raider83/) on 2022-12-19**:
Thank you for the info janindu!

We are currently working on moving our AWS from the Amazon image to Ubuntu so that we can more closely reflect our target environment.